# AppleScript: Current Tab and Argument String error

Tags: browser, safari, applescript

Why this works fine

```
tell application "Safari" to get current tab of window 1
```

and this doesn't work ?

```
set appName to "Safari"
tell application appName to get current tab of window 1
```

how to solve this?

Comment: The target application needs to be declared at compile time in order to get its scripting terminology.  Any given script term doesn't necessarily mean the same thing in different applications - what are you trying to do?

Comment: [ try tell application (name of first process whose frontmost is true) to set the clipboard to URL of current tab of front window as text end try ] . I want to get the URL of current tab of current browser and set to the clipboard

Comment: Your approach isn’t going to work very well.  The terminology of any given app is entirely up to the developer, and any similar terms or functionality between different applications is purely accidental/coincidental.  For example, **Firefox** only includes the default standard suit, which does not include `tab`.

Comment: Indeed, if you put`tab` alone in a explicitly named safari tell block, it will return 'tab', as in the window property. If you do the same with an implicit (variable-derived) tell block, it will return "    ", as in the white space (as 'tab' is normally a text constant). If you use `tabs of window 1` in the two tell blocks, it will return a list of tabs in the former and throw a 'variable' error in the latter. So probably, only the 'standard suite' would operate as expected in such a script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As some in the comments have said, storing the application in a variable for use later is unlikely to be useful. That said, it is possible, and it can be used for simple tasks.

For example:

```
set browserApp to application "Safari"
tell browserApp to activate
```

This works because `activate` doesn’t require any special dictionary.

You can partially solve your problem with “using terms from” but that presumably defeats the purpose of storing the application in a variable.

```
set browserApp to application "Safari"
using terms from application "Safari"
    tell browserApp to get name of current tab of window 1
end using terms from
```

This works, but likely isn’t what you want, since `Safari` is still hardcoded as a string around each `tell`.

If you are certain that each application you might set the variable to has the dictionary terms you need, however, you can do this, by using `run script` on a variable.

```
set browserApp to "Safari"
set getTabName to "tell application \"" & browserApp & "\" to get name of current tab of window 1"
run script getTabName
```

This works:

[image: Successfully getting current tab of variable-based app.]

The `run script` works basically as an eval. You can store the results of `run script` in a variable for later use, as anywhere else in AppleScript. You can also use it directly, such as to set the clipboard. For example:

```
set tabName to (run script getTabName)
```

or

```
set the clipboard to (run script getTabName)
```

Note that if you set `browserApp` to something that doesn’t understand that terminology, it will fail, and the error is likely to be confusing, since you don’t get the benefits of Script Editor: Script Editor will highlight the `run script` instead of the problematic text:

[image: Failed get current tab name]

In each example I chose to use “get name of” instead of just “get current tab…” for testing purposes, to make it more obvious that the script does in fact get what I’m expecting it to get. The Result should be the title of the web page in the current tab, which is easily verifiable as correct (or incorrect). You can just as well use “get url of”, or any property that the current tab has in the browser(s) you’re querying.